# Best Practice for Transforming y_pred in Tensorflow's Metric

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics

In my previous project, I need to frame an image classification task as a regression problem. I implement the regression model using Tensorflow, with standard Sequential model with a 1 node Dense layer with no activation function as the last layer. In order to measure the performance, I need to use standard classification metrics, such as accuracy and cohen kappa.

However, I can't directly use those metrics because my model is a regression model, so I need to clip and round the output before feeding them to the metrics. I use a workaround by defining my own metric, however that workaround is not practical. Therefore, I'm thinking about contributing to Tensorflow by implementing a custom transformation_function to transform y_pred by a Tensor lambda function before storing them in the __update_state method. After reading the source code, I get doubts regarding this idea. So, I'm asking out to you, fellow Tensorflow user/contributors, what is the best practice of transforming y_pred before feeding it to a metric? Is this functionality already implemented in the newest version?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you "have to" use accuracy in this context? It makes no sense to use accuracy in a regression setting (since the output is continuous and not discrete), there are other metrics you can use, but you need to justify them.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Because the problem is a classification problem. I train the model as a regression model, but in the end I clip and round the regression result, i.e. turning it to classification. I frame this as a regression because the data has ordered class (classified by 'severity' of features), therefore it makes sense to frame it as a regression.

Comment: Then make a custom metric that behaves like accuracy, you cannot use the standard accuracy metric for this.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have made a custom metric, but the problem that I want to highlight is it is very impractical to create a custom metric when a small transformation in y_pred tensor in enough to make it work.